# Create and Save an image which is stored as varbainary variable with sql in a specified directory in c#

Tags: c#, sql, file

I have an image stored in my database (sql) as a varbinary variable and I want to save it as a jpg file in a directory with c#. how should I do that? I have a method which return a variable of type `image` and now the question is how to save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you got byte array and you just need to convert it to an image file:

```
public static void ByteArrayToImage(byte[] imgByte)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgByte);
    Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
    img.Save(@"C:\imageTest.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use [Image.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.save%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Image img = YourMethodWhichReturnsImage();
string loationTosave = @"C:\fileToSave.jpg";
img.Save(loationTosave);
```